# ASP.NET MVC Action Not Getting Parameter Values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. This app has a controller with an action that looks like the following:

```
public class MyController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
  [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MyItem>))]
  public IHttpActionResult Get(string id, string filter)
  {
    IEnumerable<MyItem> results = MyItem.GetAll();
    List<MyItem> temp = results.ToList<MyItem>();

    var filtered = temp.Where(r => r.Name.Contains(filter);
    return Ok(filtered);
  }
}
```

I am calling this action using the following JavaScript, which relies on the [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) library:

```
$('#mySelect').select2({
  placeholder: 'Search here',
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/my',
    dataType: 'json',
    quietMillis: 150,
    data: function (term, page) {
      return {
        id: '123',
        filter: term
      };
    },
    results: function (data, page) {
      return { results: data };
    }
  }
});
```

This code successfully reaches the controller action. However, when I look at `id` and `filter` in the watch window, I see the following errors:

```
The name 'id' does not exist in the current context 
The name 'filter' does not exist in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I call the MVC action from my JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also show your routes please? In addition to David's answer (which sounds right) it could be around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing actual data as the parameters, you're passing a function:

```
data: function (term, page) {
  return {
    id: '123',
    filter: term
  };
}
```

Unless something *invokes* that function, the result will never be evaluated.  Generally one would just pass data by itself:

```
data: {
  id: '123',
  filter: term
}
```

If, however, in your code there's a particular reason (not shown in the example) to use a function, you'll want to evaluate that function in order for the resulting value to be set as the `data`:

```
data: (function (term, page) {
  return {
    id: '123',
    filter: term
  };
})()
```

---

However, these errors also imply a second problem, probably related to however you're trying to debug this:

> The name 'id' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'filter' does not exist in the current context

Even if no values were being passed, `id` and `filter` still *exist* in the scope of the action method.  They may be `null` or empty strings, but the variables exist.  It's not clear where you're seeing that error, but it's definitely not in the scope of the action method.